# Something wrong in c++ code

Tags: c++, casting

Please what wrong in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


unsigned __int32 ConvertToChars(std::vector<int> container, char** pChars)
{
    *pChars = (char*)&container[0];

    return container.size() * sizeof(int);
}


void ConvertToIntegers(char* chars, short size, std::vector<int>& container)
{
    int count = size / sizeof(int);

    int* pIntegers = (int*)chars;

    for(int i=0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        container.push_back(*(pIntegers++));
    }
}


void Print(const std::vector<int>& container)
{
    for(int i=0; i < container.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << container[i] << std::endl;
    }
}


void main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec1;

    vec1.push_back(1);
    vec1.push_back(2);
    vec1.push_back(3);

    char* buffer = 0;

    short bufferSize = ConvertToChars(vec1, &buffer);

    std::vector<int> vec2;

    ConvertToIntegers(buffer, bufferSize, vec2);

    Print(vec2);

    char c;

    std::cin >> c;
}
```

function Print prints values:

- -572662307
- -842150451
- -572662307

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copying the container when you pass it to `ConvertToChars`, then taking a pointer to one of its elements, then seeing the copy go out of scope, which invalidates your pointer.

Comment: @Jimmy yes! it seems like i cannot accept it quickly) 1 minute)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand the point of your program, but part of your problem is in your `ConvertToIntegers` function, where you make your program interpret a `char *` as `int *`.

```
int* pIntegers = (int*)chars;

for(int i=0; i < count; ++i)
{
    container.push_back(*(pIntegers++));
}
```

You're interpreting the underlying bytes as `int` types, which could lead to the numbers you're seeing. I'm surprised you're not running into segmentation faults as this would cause you to overstep the block of the memory pointed to by the original `char *`.